# Как отключить подчеркивание помарок в vscode для ruby?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ruby

Не могу никак найти галочку в настройках чтоб отключить подчеркивание волнистой линией. Как это откоючить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [ruby] тут, я полагаю, не при чем.

Comment: У разных языков же разные расширения, в том числе и те, которые подсветкой занимаются, разве не так? В любом случае хотелось бы оффнуть эти помарки

Comment: Кажется, [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43454967/disable-wavy-underline-in-vs-code) то что вам надо. К слову сказать, ссылка с первой страницы поиска в яндексе заголовка вашего вопроса.

Comment: @Глеб Если честно, искал эту настройку два дня, перерыл кучу гайдов и статей, ничего не находил. Огромное спасибо)